number decimal digits
The \test command below always rounds a number to 3 decimal places. How to modify this command so that a number not to be rounded unless an optional argument is explicitly provided?
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\test}{O{3} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

\begin{document}

\test{pi} % without an argument, don't round pi. 

\test[5]{pi} % with an argument , round number to 5 decimal places

\end{document}


Use o and an IfNoValueTF test

a LuaLatex version
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
   function round(num,n)
            return string.format('%.' .. n .. 'f',num)
    end
\end{luacode*}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usevar}{om}{%
\directlua{tex.print({\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{round(#2, #1)}})}%
}
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usevar}

\begin{document}

\directlua{
  b = 0.24
  h = 5.1
  A = b * (b+h)
  I2 = b * (b+h)^3/12
}

\?{I2}

\?[3]{I2}

\?{math.pi}

\?[5]{math.pi}

\end{document}


\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\test}{om}{%
\IfNoValueTF{#1}{\fpeval{#2}}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}%
}

\begin{document}

\test{pi} 

\test[5]{pi} 

\end{document}


Maybe, \fpeval{\IfNoValueTF{#1}{#2}{round(#2, #1)}} is nicer.

The OpTeX's \expr macro does exactly what you want:
\def\_decdigits{12} % default number of decimal digits

\expr{math.pi}

\expr[4]{math.pi}

\bye

